# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I'm trying to using use Hangfire to execute a Recurring Job but got this exception

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyModel' while attempting to activate
```

**NOTICE**: It throw exception on **my model** not **my service** so I don't understand about that. I also inject that model in the constructor of my current class.

Do anyone face this issue before? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I did register all of my model but the deepest model I pass string into the constructor and it show this now:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: No constructor for type 'System.String' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.
```

Comment: Your service might have constructor or any expected params so your service is not resolved by the container

Comment: Du you use ASP.NET or ASP.NET CORE?

Comment: Also please show some code of you container and constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Asp.Net  default dependency injection has nothing defined for your type

Try something like  this

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService>(_ => new MyService("value here"));
```

In your case you have to initalize your model.

Comment: My server put string into parameter and now it show this message:  System.InvalidOperationException: No constructor for type 'System.String' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.